# how to use diff command ignoring last enter?

Tags: unix, io, comparison, diff

I'd like to use diff Unix command to compare between output files.

However , sometimes there is a redundant "\n" in the end of the output , but I still want to consider files as the same.

say I've this output:

```
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

and:

```
XXXXX
XXXXX\n
```

(cant get it to show an empty line , so i wrote \n)

I'd like to able to use unix diff command stil consider these two outputs as equal.

to make myself clear , i only want to ignore **last** enter ("\n") only. the rest shouldn't be ignored.

for example , these two outputs should not be considred equal:

```
XXXXX

XXXXX
```

and

```
XXXXX
XXXXX
```

thanks

Comment: Do you have an actual `\r\n` in the file, or just an extra empty line (`\n`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the `-b` option:

```
-b, --ignore-space-change
          ignore changes in the amount of white space
```

http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?diff

If you only wish to exclude the last possible new line try removing it with sed before piping the result to diff:

```
sed '${/^$/d}' file1 | diff - file2
```

Comment: ... or `-B`, that `ignore changes whose lines are all blank`

Comment: @barsju I only need to ignore last enter . all other char spaces/enters does matter to me. look at my edit. Thanks

Comment: Added another solution using sed